# mysql match...against by referencing string variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find a match in two different columns using input from two different form fields in a PHP form. I am referencing the two string variables that are input into the form in my mysql code, but it is returning an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'MATCH (abcdef) AGAINST name' at line 1

I have tried a few variations of the syntax, but with no success.

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentname']);
$num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentnum']);
$qw = "SELECT name FROM students MATCH ($name) AGAINST name";
$qw1 = "SELECT studentnum FROM students MATCH ($num) AGAINST studentnum";
$namematch = mysql_query($qw) or die(mysql_error());
$nummatch = mysql_query($qw1) or die(mysql_error());

if (($namematch || $nummatch) == FALSE) {
    die('Name or student number do not match those on record');
}
```

Comment: What error is it returning? (Put this info in your question.)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MATCH (abcdef) AGAINST name' at line 1

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your parameters backwards in the MATCH clause. You have:

> $qw = "SELECT name FROM students MATCH (**$name**) AGAINST **name**";

Instead it should be:

> $qw = "SELECT name FROM students MATCH (**name**) AGAINST **$name**";

In other words, MATCH (**column**) AGAINST (**parameter**), not the other way around.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are missing `WHERE` in your SQL statements.

Second, you have your arguments in `MATCH` and `AGAINST` reversed. `MATCH` should be given the column names as arguments.

E.g.

`SELECT name FROM students MATCH ($name) AGAINST name`

should be

`SELECT name FROM students WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('$name')`

and similarly adjust your second query.

Comment: I tried correcting the syntax as you described, but it is still returning the same error.

Comment: @Graham See edit. Does this resolve? I'm seeing conflicting info about quotes in the AGAINST param.

Comment: I tried what you specified in the edit, and made sure that everything is compatible with full text search. Now I am getting the error "Unknown column ".." in where clause"

Comment: Well I assume `name` and `studentnum` are column names in your `students` table. So I'm stumped otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

try this, use in_array to match array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qw)){
$namematch[] = $row['name'];
}

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qw)){
$nummatch[] = $row['studentnum'];
}

if(in_array($name,$namematch)){
echo 0;
}else{
echo 1;
}
```

***NOTE** Please avoid  to use mysql. I suggest use MYSQLi rather than use MYSQL. Just FYI.